# How to load javascript on custom page template?

Tags: pages

I have a custom page template where I would like to load some javascript. I suppose I could always include the javascript in the actual file, but that seems ugly. Is there any way to identify if WordPress is loading my custom-page.php file so I can enqueue the script only on that page?

It should work dynamically, so checking page id is not an option.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [**`is_page_template`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page_template) to check if you template is being used and load your scripts based on that ex:

Add this code to your functions.php:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855');
function Load_Template_Scripts_wpa83855(){
    if ( is_page_template('custom-page.php') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script('my-script', 'path/to/script.js');
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am tring to use a javascript from one of my plugins and it says: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this .....

```
 add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpm_load_script_for_template', 1000 );
        function wpm_load_script_for_template( $template ){
             if(is_page_template('lead_capture_full.php')){

// standard code for adding js

            }
        return $template; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add new `wp_enqueue_scripts` in your template file before `get_header()` call:

```php
/**
 * Template name: My page
 */

function my_page_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_script('my_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-page-script.js', [], '1.0', true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_page_scripts' );

get_header();
```